# Angular splice animation

Tags: angularjs

I try to include class "animated" on index to splice, but i dont understand the follow erros..

Splice normally function, but..

```
function deleteS(item, index) {

    var deferred = allDB.remove({section: $rootScope.$stateParams.section, id: item.id});

    deferred.$promise.then(function () {

        var itemIndex = $rootScope.items.indexOf(item);
        $rootScope.selected     = [];

        console.log(itemIndex);

         $("tr:eq(" +itemIndex+ ")").addClass('animated fadeOutDown', 
             setTimeout(
                 function(){
                     $rootScope.items.splice(itemIndex, 1)
                     $mdToast.show($mdToast.simple({position: 'top right'}).content(item.id + ' ....Deletados!'))
                 }, 500)
         );

    });

    return deferred.$promise;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my english, I am here to explain more details.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Bad idea using jquery at the controller! There's ng-animate that does the job when the ng-repeat changes: http://www.nganimate.org/

Comment: class is added in the wrong index

Comment: @Fals i using angular 1.4.3, dont working for me..

Comment: @MarcoRiesco Why not? ng-animate is not version specific. Just add the css code to you site and use the directive at the ng-repeat. They way yoyu did It's a bad pratice, and if you don't use $compile the way you are doing with jquery will fail.

Comment: I resolved put over animated out project, for this moment..